# Checking ifstream files for being empty

Tags: c++

I have following structure to read files:

```
while (index != 5) {
    fileName = "Files/a" + to_string(index) + ".txt";
    ifstream fileRead(fileName);

    while (fileRead >> ID >> Name) {

        cout << ID << "\t" << Name<< "\t" << endl;
    }

    index = index + 1;
}
```

I have all of that 5 files, but some of them are empty, and if it is empty, I want to show message "File a5 is empty". I tried things from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/13699/) , but that didn't work

And do I have to close ifStream?

Comment: `fileRead.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof();`

Comment: @DimChtz , thank you. neat. Do I have to do fileread.close() at the end? I know that I have to do that when writing, but when reading, not sure

Comment: Well no, that's the point of using classes and their destructors.

Comment: Addendum to @DimChtz 's comment: The destructor will take care of closing the file for you, but it won't close the file until the destructor is run. This will not happen if you try to open the file again in the same scope.

Comment: @user4581301: in this case, the `ifstream` is local to the loop body, so it will go out of scope on each loop iteration